# Programmatically check if Core Data entities are indexed

Tags: sqlite, core-data, indexing, nsentitydescription, nsattributedescription

I am currently working with a library that sits between Core Data and the sqlite database (i.e. it handles a lot of the Core Data calls, and translates them into SQL queries). 
I have noticed that when creating the sqlite tables, it doesn't add any indexes. I have attempted to add in this functionality, but cannot see where the Core Data model 'Indexed tick box' property is stored.

I have access to every NSEntityDescription and NSAttributeDescription, which I would have assumed would be where the 'Indexed' property would be listed. However, the compoundIndexes array is nil and there doesn't appear to be another index property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSPropertyDescription` has a `isIndexed` attribute.
(`NSAttributeDescription` is a subclass of this.)

Comment: I had thought I had missed something simple. Turned out I was correct.